# Changing the decimal separator

Tags: java, android

I want to change the separator for numbers in my app. I tried it with decimal format.

```
DecimalFormat x=new DecimalFormat("##'##'##.###");
textview.setText(x.format("1564643");
```

But I got the exception as *the symbol ( ' ) is not supported by decimalformat*. I don't know even what I did was right or not. I just need a format like `12'23'52`. And one more requirement is , the decimal place separator ( . ) should be replaced as ( , ).

Can anyone help me. Thank you. :)

Comment: Check my below answer it works properly

Comment: You can check my answer.

Comment: If the answer is working mark as accepted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1.Use `new DecimalFormat("##,##");` to format**

**2.Use `replaceAll(",", "'");` to replace**

**3.Use `setText` to set text to the `TextView`**

Try this.

```
DecimalFormat mFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,##");
String yourFormattedString = mFormat.format(1564643);
String result = yourFormattedString.replaceAll(",", "'");
Log.e("DecimalFormat", result);
textview.setText(result);
```

**Output**

```
1'56'46'43
```

Comment: Yes even i tried your code it is working but this is not the correct way of doing. If you want to format 100 or 1000 values each time you need to replace all the `,` with `'`.

Comment: Yes ,you are right .But that's one way I can think of it .Your answer is right .Thank you for your explanation .@SushinPv .I upvote you .

Comment: Thank you, it works.But whenever i want to use the number,i need to replace all separator as "" .

Comment: @jothi Yes you have to. Check the below answer

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('\'');

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,#0",otherSymbols);
//If you want to parse the String use 
//formatter.format(Integer.parseInt("1564643"))
textview.setText(formatter.format(1564643));
```

Answer (score 1):

I Use this class for EditText. You can use part of that to solve your problem.

```
public class NumberTextWatcherWithSeperator implements TextWatcher {

private EditText editText;

public NumberTextWatcherWithSeperator(EditText editText) {
    this.editText = editText;
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    try {
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        String value = editText.getText().toString();

        if (!value.equals("")) {

            if (value.startsWith(".")) {
                editText.setText("0.");
            }
            if (value.startsWith("0") && !value.startsWith("0.")) {
                editText.setText("");

            }

            String str = editText.getText().toString().replaceAll("'", "");
            if (!value.equals(""))
                editText.setText(getDecimalFormattedString(str));
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
        }
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
}

private static String getDecimalFormattedString(String value) {
    StringTokenizer lst = new StringTokenizer(value, ".");
    String str1 = value;
    String str2 = "";
    if (lst.countTokens() > 1) {
        str1 = lst.nextToken();
        str2 = lst.nextToken();
    }
    StringBuilder str3 = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    int j = -1 + str1.length();
    if (str1.charAt(-1 + str1.length()) == '.') {
        j--;
        str3 = new StringBuilder(".");
    }
    for (int k = j; ; k--) {
        if (k < 0) {
            if (str2.length() > 0)
                str3.append(".").append(str2);
            return str3.toString();
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            str3.insert(0, "'");
            i = 0;
        }
        str3.insert(0, str1.charAt(k));
        i++;
    }

}
}
```

and in your activity use like this:

```
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.et);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcherWithSeperator(editText));
```